# jBPM final server (full) commercial use

Tags: jboss, drools, redhat, jbpm, kie

We have the requirement of configuring the rules in UI by the business users. The jBPM seems a perfect fit which has the Business Central to design the rules and backed with Kie Server for the rules execution. The docker image (jboss/jbpm-server-full:latest) which is the combination of Business central and Kie Server we are planning to use.I noticed that it uses Wildfly Server instead of Jboss(which requires subscription) and comes up with GNU license.Can someone please explain whether i can use the software for commercial use or not.Also please explain whether the Business central and Kie Server has any license for commercial use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every KIE project is under the [Apache 2.0 License](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/LICENSE-Apache-2.0.txt) so it's perfectly legal to use for commercial use.

See also [this answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-use-a-apache-v2-licensed-driver-for-a-commercial-project-without-revealing)

Comment: Thanks for the quick note Luca. We are going with docker image to bring this solution into our project. Is there a way to customize the css files, add logo,change the backround color inside the docker image. Please note that we are using Azure container services to host this docker image.